# How does EF4 compare with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

Is it any better? I heard the CodeFirst extension but is it ready for primetime. Please share your experience with development, any performance overheads, etc.

Comment: http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a timely question, as I was wondering the exact same thing.  I am trying to create a serious e-commerce model and I am trying to keep my POCOs free of persistence concerns as well as trying to stay true to Domain Driven Design.  So far, I am very wary, and I am on the fence about whether I should jump ship to NHibernate.  The only thing keeping me from doing so is that I assume that Microsoft will improve (and quickly).

Some of the biggest problems so far:

- Inability to finely control object materialization.  EF calls the zero-arg constructor on your POCO, and this is a behavior you cannot change.
- No enum support.  The community has been screaming -- screaming! -- for this, and it hasn't happened.  The workarounds are terrible, and pollute your domain model.
- Weird mapping bugs when trying to control column names and relationships in the database.  The main ones I can think of are with compound keys and many-to-many relationships.  These can be worked around, and I assume these will be fixed by release time, but they are frustrating nonetheless.
- Bad SQL.  I also do DBA work, and the SQL that EF generates (with or without Code-First) is atrocious.

And this is just the tip of the iceberg:  I am only starting to learn EF4 and I'm running into awful roadblocks.  As I think of more reasons, I'll add them here.  I'm still struggling through it.

(I wonder whether the community will give it another vote of "no confidence.")

---

More:

- To add to the "Weird mapping bugs" problem:  You cannot control the name of a column if it participates in a self-referencing relationship (for example, if you have a hierarchy).  I assume this will be fixed in the final release.
- Lack of batching, resulting in multiple roundtrips to the database.  For example, how do you delete a bunch of items from a collection?  *Load all entities into memory and delete them one at a time.*  A smaller gripe is the number of DB hits when inserting into tables that participate in an inheritance relationship.
- No intelligent way to deal with model changes.  EF Code-First loves to completely drop your entire database if it needs to change the schema.
- Few extensibility points.  You can literally count on one hand the number of events that EF4 allows you to subscribe to (and Code-First doesn't provide much more).

Comment: This is very interesting and useful. I hope more SO folks comment before trolls close this thread.

Comment: I would like to hear more, too, as I am /very/ conflicted about committing to EF4 Code-first.

Comment: This is a very good list. All valid points which i have experienced over the past few months. I'd also throw in EF4's lack of `GEOGRAPHY` data type support (SQL Server), and inability to pass user defined table types (also SQL Server) to stored procs. To combat the former, i had to use triggers, to combat the latter i degaraded to classic ADO.NET.

Comment: In addition to the lack of GEOGRAPHY, I'll add the lack of HIERARCHYID.  However, we may be turning this into an EF4/SQL Server wishlist instead of addressing "Is EF4 ready for prime-time?" and the related question "Can EF4 reasonably do what NHibernate does?"  (I wish I could start a bounty on this question.  I'd gladly donate all of my points for comprehensive opinions.)

Comment: I believe NHibernate also calls the empty arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As for me - I prefer EF but with some enhancements. Basically EF offers to you the following advantages:

- Visual Model Editor
- Database/Model Update wizard (instead of manual XML changes - what is terrible for me)

Also, I'm using 3-rd party commercial tools based on EF and L2S ([LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect)) that provide for me the following features:

- [Geography support](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/postgis-and-entity-framework.html)
- [Optimized SQL generation](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-sql-generation-enhancements-for-in-clause.html)
- Product absolutely integrated to Visual Studio
- Smart database update wizard (synchronization mode)

Comment: NHibernate also has lots of different designers. You can use it with fluent and automappings with no xml

Comment: Can you post a link for these designers?